# VB.NET How to use the Math.Round() function to round the percentage to a whole number

Tags: vb.net, percentage

Noob here so apologies in advance if this is not worded correctly.

I have a function which is calculating two Integer variables to work out a percentage.

```
Public Function CalculatePercentCorrect() As Double

    Return (Correct / Tries) * 100

  End Function
```

I am then using this property to display within a label

```
If game.CheckAnswer(answer) = True Then
  AnswerLabel.Text = _
    String.Format("Correct! Your score is {0} out of {1} for {2} percent.", _
                   game.Correct, game.Tries, game.CalculatePercentCorrect())
Else
  AnswerLabel.Text = _
  String.Format("Incorrect. Your score is {0} out of {1} for {2} percent.", _
                game.Correct, game.Tries, game.CalculatePercentCorrect())
End If
```

However I require the percentage to be rounded up to a whole number, as it may show 66.6666666666667 percent for example.

I believe I should use the Math.Round function, however I'm not entirely sure how to use it in my example.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: To round up, I suggest you use [Math.Ceiling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Don't do this yourself, leave it up to the format specifier.  Use {2:N0}.  Multiplying by 100 isn't necessary either, use {2:P0}

Comment: Hans Passant's solution is pretty clever. Here's a link to the built-in [numeric formatters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: That is pretty clever, and not something I have used before. I'll give that a try. Thank you all

Comment: @HansPassant `P0` doesn't round up everything: e.g. 0.654->"65 %", whereas the OP specified "I require the percentage to be rounded up to a whole number."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Math.Round Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN. Since it returns a Double when rounding a Double, for you it would be as simple as:

```
String.Format("Correct! Your score is {0} out of {1} for {2} percent.", _
    game.Correct, game.Tries, Math.Round(game.CalculatePercentCorrect()))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew it would be something simple!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to round up you can use

```
math.ceiling(game.CalculatePercentCorrect())
```

Comment: round( ) rounds to the nearest integer, ceiling( ) rounds up